# Django 2.0: TextInput in ModelChoiceField shows id instead if value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I changed *ModelChoiceField* to be shown as a **TextInput**.
I have a field named 'filename' of this type: `models.ForeignKey('Filename', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)` in a class as follow:

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    filename = models.ForeignKey('Filename', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)


class Filename(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

This is part of my 'forms.py' I use show form in frontend after defining the template (myappname/templates/myappname/event_edit.html)

**forms.py**

```
class EventEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if data is not None:
            data = data.copy()
            if data['filename']:
                f, f_created = Filename.objects.get_or_create(nome=data['filename'])
                data['filename'] = m.id
        super(EventEditForm, self).__init__(data=data, *args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['filename'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Filename.objects.all(), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'value':self.instance.filename}))
        self.fields['filename'].required = False

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['name', 'filename']
```

and this is my **event_edit.html**:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in event_form %}
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{field.label}}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                {{ field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            {{ field.errors }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg center-block">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that if I override ModelChoiceField to be a TextInput the 'filename' field shows *id* instead of showing field *name*.
Otherwise, If I leave it as a Choice Field it correctly shows value instead of id.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve, but can you help us to understand why you want the `Filename.name` to be displayed in that field? If you submit the form, it won't validate because it is expecting a `Filename.pk`.

Comment: Hi,
I wish to show name because if I show id I cannot know the name of file associated to that id. The page is an 'edit_form' and for this I should have a chance to see the name and eventually change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments and the code in `EventEditForm`, you want a form that will:

- display the `Event.name` and the linked `Filename.name`
- use the submitted name to update `Event.name`
- use the submitted filename to lookup or create a `Filename` and update `Event.filename`

This should work:

```
class EventEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Calling form.save() will:

    * update the Event.name
    * update the Event.filename with a Filename instance 
      found or created using the supplied name

    """
    fname = forms.CharField(
        label='Filename',
        required=False,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['name',]
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['fname'] = self.instance.filename

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(EventEditForm, self).save(commit=False)
        cleaned_fname = self.cleaned_data['fname']
        if cleaned_fname:
            f, f_created = Filename.objects.get_or_create(name=cleaned_fname)
            instance.filename = f
        else:
            instance.filename = None
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```